# Watcher is only fired once when watching prop in Vue3 composition API

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a parent component `Search` that passes the prop `query` to a child component `Results`.

**Search.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="query" type="text" />
    <Results :query="query" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import Results from "./Results.vue";
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Search",
  components: { Results },
  data() {
    return {
      query: "",
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

**Results.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>{{ query }} ( {{ query.length }})</div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineProps, watch, computed } from "vue";
const { query } = defineProps({
  query: {
    type: String,
    default: "",
  },
});

const queryLength = computed(() => query.length);

watch(
  () => query,
  () => {
    console.debug("Watcher was fired.");
  }, {immediate: true}
);

watch(queryLength, () => {
  console.debug("Watcher was fired.");
});

</script>
```

The watcher for the `query` prop never fires, except when I add `{immediate: true}` to the watcher, but then it does not fire on updates. It also doesn't do anything when I add a computed property based on the `query` prop.

The strange thing is that when displaying the `query` prop, the value is rendered.

Here's [the simplest version of my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/small-tdd-w3cmsn?file=/src/components/Results.vue). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot destructure props directly as you do in

```
const { query } = defineProps({...})
```

or, to be precise, you can do it, but the resulting values won't be reactive - `query` will be a simple string. So the value will be rendered, but watchers (among other things) will not work.

To avoid the error, either do not destructure at all or use the [toRefs()](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#torefs) utility function:

```
const props = defineProps({...})
const { query } = toRefs(props);
// or for a single prop:
const query = toRef(props, 'query')
```